# Liferay portal deployment going into loop

Tags: spring, tomcat, liferay-6

We are using STS 3.4 to develop Spring portlets for Liferay 6.1.2. When we deploy the project onto the server by droping that on the server view, the deployment never gets completed.

It says the deployment is complete and portlets are ready to use but it again reinitiates the deployment process.

Any idea why this endless deployment loop is happening?

Comment: before directly droping project in to server first add portlet into server by right click on server->add or remove portlet after that compile it by right click on project ->liferay->sdk->compile and then deploy by again right click on project -> liferay->sdk ->deploy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if STS is aware of Liferay's additional deployment process (or if you need/use it): Liferay typically processes a WAR file before actual deployment to tomcat, thus you should drop your WAR file to Liferay's `deploy` folder. This might add some libraries from Liferay itself (depending on your configuration in `liferay-*.xml` files or some other necessities that I don't remember.

Especially if you use Liferay's Plugins SDK (you don't state if you do or if you don't). If you indeed use it, you might want to try the Ant target `direct-deploy` for building the WAR file: The result of this should be able to deploy directly to tomcat. I'm assuming that STS omits the Liferay deployment process (and `direct-deploy` would mimic it). I hope (from memory) that it was available on 6.1 already.

Can't go without the hint that you should upgrade.